# LUT to avoid uint32_t power exponent

Tags: c++, class, image-processing, lookup-tables, exponential

I need to perform a power exponential operation to all the pixel in an image. Which is a very heavy process.
The exponent is constant (float), and the base is a uint32_t (result of multiplying 2 uint16_t) 
I'm trying to figure out if I can write a LUT so that I only have to look for the values instell of calculate them for ech pixel.

Right now I'm doing this: `powf((exposure * color) , invGamma)`

and is too slow

I  had already solved the problem with a base on uint8_t, but a LUT with 2^32 elements is too big.

With uint8_t I used this:

```
void colorCorrection::vidGammaLUT()
{
    for (uint16_t u16Count = 0; u16Count < 256; u16Count++)
    {
        m_au8GammaRgbLUT[u16Count] = u8clamp(static_cast<int32_t>(255.0f * pow(u16Count/255.0f, m_settings.GammaRgb)));
    }
}
```

Comment: How slow is "slow"? 4GB lookup table does not look that big either (though i'm not sure whether it will be faster than normal calculation.

Comment: @VTT A multi-GiB lookup table strikes me as fairly big — and I work in genomics, where such tables are par for the course, and yet there’s substantial effort being undertaken to reduce their footprint as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

As exponentiation is distributive over product, you can apply the gamma exponent to exposure and color separately, and multiply after the lookup. 2^16 elements is more manageable.

In practice, not all these bits are significant (reality rarely exceeds 12 bits) and you can probably drop a few to further reduce.